# How to change app theme before first recomposition in Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme, darkmode, android-dark-theme

I have composable `MainScreen` and `SettingsScreen`. They all share a common ViewModel `SettingsViewModel` which is responsible for reading and saving theme settings.

In the `MainActivity`, before creating `MainScreen`, I get `SettingsViewModel` that internally receives data about which theme is used by app (via DataStore). Then I pass the theme as the app's theme parameter.

But the problem is that the default value (from ViewModel) is loaded first, and after delay - actual value from DataStore. What am I missing? Why is there such a huge delay (almost a second) and how to avoid it?

My `MainActivity`

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val viewModel: SettingsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
            val colorScheme = viewModel.colorScheme.collectAsState()// TODO loaded with default value first :(
            Log.d("TAG", "MainActivity theme $colorScheme")
            MyAppTheme(
                darkTheme = when(colorScheme.value){
                    ColorScheme.AUTO -> isSystemInDarkTheme()
                    ColorScheme.LIGHT -> false
                    ColorScheme.DARK -> true
                }
            ) {
                // MainScreen
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `SettingsViewModel`

```
enum class ColorScheme{
    AUTO, LIGHT, DARK
}

@HiltViewModel
class SettingsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val settingsRepository: SettingsRepository
): ViewModel() {
    private val _colorScheme = MutableStateFlow(ColorScheme.AUTO)
    val colorScheme: StateFlow<ColorScheme>
        get() = _colorScheme

    init {
        Log.d("TAG", "SettingsViewModel init")
        // Load settings
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _colorScheme.emit(ColorScheme.values()[settingsRepository.loadColorScheme()])
            Log.d("TAG", "SettingsViewModel load & emit")
        }
    }

    fun setColorScheme(colorScheme: ColorScheme){
        _colorScheme.tryEmit(colorScheme)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            settingsRepository.saveColorScheme(colorScheme)
        }
    }
}
```

My Logcat

```
2023-08-13 11:34:22.315 SettingsViewModel init
2023-08-13 11:34:22.326 MainActivity theme = MutableState(value=AUTO)
2023-08-13 11:34:23.105 SettingsViewModel load & emit
2023-08-13 11:34:23.124 MainActivity theme = MutableState(value=LIGHT)
```

I already tried to remove default value from `SettingsViewModel`, but at the time of the first `MainScreen` recomposition, the theme variable has not yet been initialized. Maybe you can somehow postpone `MainScreen` recomposition until the app theme is known?

Comment: Have you considered adding a splash screen?

Comment: This will not solve the root of the problem. What color should I show on the Splash Screen background? How can I detect this BEFORE displaying the Splash Screen? This is the main problem. 

I know that this problem can be solved, but I do not know how.

For example, the official ChatGPT Android app shows Splash Screen background in the right color of the selected theme (regardless of the system theme), instantly when the app is launched.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the Theme from your settings database outside of your activity, and store it in a global variable. And then load that global variable in your ViewModel's `init` block, instead of loading whatever default value you currently use.

The easiest way to do this is by creating a persistent Application class, and anything you run in the Application's `onCreate()` will be run immediately when the Application wakes up, before any of your activities are initialized.

**in your Manifest:**

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        android:persistent="true"
        ...
</application>
```

**and your Application class:**

```
class App: Application() {

    lateinit var colorScheme: ColorScheme

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // read the theme variable here (probably inside an IO CoroutineScope)
        colorScheme = ...
    }
}
```

and you can access the variable anywhere in your app by calling `App.colorScheme`